# MSAccess: How do I create a form with a field that updates multiple tables that share that field?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a database that currently has 5 tables.  Each table is linked by the Primary Key field, "Lot #", with each table containing data in a different category related to those lot numbers.  I currently have forms for each of these tables that allow for the entry of the various data, but I would like to set it up so that new lot numbers are only entered on the form for the "Manufacturing Table", and then that data is auto-populated into the Lot # fields of the 4 other tables.

Is it possible to set up a form in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do it in a form when you can do it in the database?  Just set up relationships for the tables (linking on Lot #) and then set them up for cascading updates.

See [Microsoft's KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304466) and particularly the section about cascading updates and deletes.

Comment: My only concern is that I had to import a bunch of Excel data into this database.  This data was organized into 5 different spreadsheets, each with it's own lot #'s, and while most of the lot #'s are the same, there are a few lots here and there that differ. The lot numbers listed on the Manufacturing Table are the "gold standard" for what lots we care about, but there will be some "orphan lot numbers" on the other tables that aren't present on the Manufacturing Table, and I'm not sure if that will create a problem when I attempt to set up cascading updates.  Do you know how that would work?

Comment: You've got to fix your data first.  If it's out of sync, your database is useless.  Cascading will fix it for any new entries you add.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was able to clean up my data and establish a 1 to 1 relationship between the "Lot #" field on the Manufacturing Table and the "Lot #" field on each of the other tables.  I then established referential integrity and enabled cascading updates for each relationship.  However, this only seems to cascade "edits", as when I attempted to create a new Lot # on the Manufacturing Table, it didn't cascade that new Lot # into the other tables.  Does this function not work with cascading new records?

Comment: It should.  That's the whole point of cascading; to prevent you from needing to add identical fields to all your tables.  Do a little googling and see if there's something you missed when you set it up.